# How to delay an animation in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm kinda new to jquery and I have created an hide/show animation for a page, what this animation does is when you hover on the link "Call us" it shows a phone (1800blabla) but now I've been asked that the phone number should have a delay before it hides back again. I will appreciate any help. Please find the code below.

HTML

```
<ul class="top-links">
<li>
    <div id="call-us">
     <a class="showPhoneNumberLink" href="#">Call Us</a>
      <span class="showPhoneNumberNumber">1.888.227.6482</span>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
    $('#call-us a.showPhoneNumberLink').mouseenter(
      function() {
            var _this = $(this);
            _this.hide();
            _this.parent().width(0);
            _this.parent().find('span').show();
            _this.parent().animate({ 'width': '78px' }, 500);
                return false;
    });
$('ul.top-links').mouseleave(
        function() {
            var _this = $('#call-us a.showPhoneNumberLink');
            _this.show();
            _this.parent().find('span').hide();
            _this.parent().animate({ 'width': '45px' }, 800);
                return false;
    });
```

CSS

```
#call-us span.showPhoneNumberNumber {display:none}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an update. Notice the setTimeout function wrapping the methods inside mouseleave.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#call-us a.showPhoneNumberLink').mouseenter(
              function() {
                    var _this = $(this);
                    _this.hide();
                    _this.parent().width(0);
                    _this.parent().find('span').show();
                    _this.parent().animate({ 'width': '78px' }, 500);
                        return false;
            });
        $('ul.top-links').mouseleave(
                function() {
                    setTimeout(function() { 
                        var _this = $('#call-us a.showPhoneNumberLink');
                        _this.show();
                        _this.parent().find('span').hide();
                        _this.parent().animate({ 'width': '45px' }, 800);
                            return false;
                    }, 1000);
            });
        });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

    <ul class="top-links">
    <li>
        <div id="call-us">
         <a class="showPhoneNumberLink" href="#">Call Us</a>
          <span style="display:none;" class="showPhoneNumberNumber">1.888.227.6482</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This work just fine, but... I'm looking for the phone number to slide from the right.

Answer (score 4):

To delay three seconds:

```
_this.parent()
    .delay(3000)
    .animate({ 'width': '78px' }, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the `setTimeout()` method in JavaScript. A clear, concise tutorial on how to use it is available [here.](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-using-setinterval-and-settimeout)